# Trying to use PHP variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, countdown, countdowntimer

I am trying to bring a php variable into my javascript code to use for a countdown timer. Because of the other functions happening based on the timestamp php variable, I need to to be in php as well.

```
<?php  $access = '1443907640'; ?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var access = <?php echo $access ?>;
        var note = $('.note'),

        ts = (new Date(access * 1000)).getTime() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;


        $('.countdown').countdown({
        timestamp: ts,
        callback: function(days, hours, minutes, seconds) {

            var message = "";

            message += days + "<small class='opacity'>D</small>, ";
            message += hours + "<small class='opacity'>H</small>, ";
            message += minutes + "<small class='opacity'>M</small>, ";
            message += seconds + "<small class='opacity'>S</small>";

            note.html(message);

        }


        });
    });
</script>
```

Then I call call it with html here but doesn't work

```
<div class="note"></div>
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing in the js console?

Comment: Since you use Jquery, do you call it from within `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Not seeing errors in console. I am mainly a php guy, not very good with js and jquery. I am only trying to use it so the countdown timer counts down by the second and isn't static

Comment: Just tried that solution, now seeing this in console ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Can you post how you call this function?

Comment: If `$` isn't defined, your JQuery isn't active. Do you load the library in the header?

Comment: You mean `<div class="note"></div>`

Comment: Ah crap, no I didn't. Just put it in and got this `TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function`

Comment: DId you also fix the comma/semicolon typo Zakaria pointed out?

Comment: Actually it works in another instance with the comma. But I just tried it and no change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91267/discussion-between-some-non-descript-user-and-dan-henry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real problem in your code is in the end of this line :

```
var note = $('.note'),
```

Replace `,` by `;` and it should work.

**NOTE :** line `var access = <?php echo $access ?>;` work fine in my test.

---

To solve the following error :

```
TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function
```

You should add `jquery.countdown` script :

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.1.0/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really? I tried that and am getting `TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function`

Comment: You can see that i talk about a line and not the whole code... to solve the previous error see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok did that, made the error disappear but still blank http://massblogprofits.com/get-launched/test.php

Comment: Ok, i cant see the class `countdown` in your code so please try to follow some tuto in jquery.countdown for a better implementation.

Comment: Your solution plus forgetting to load my plugin, work now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider to put an semicolon after your PHP-echo.

`<?php echo $access; ?>`

or the short-and-dirty version:

`<?=$access?>`

in line 4:

```
var access = <?=$access?>;
```

or

```
var access = '<?=$access?>'; //if $access would be typeof string
```

Comment: 4th line in his code, isn't it?

Comment: I have it as         var access = "<?php echo $access; ?>";

Comment: yes! And you normally can omit the 'php' after those <? . I edited my post to make this clear.

Comment: I cannot comment the other Answer: If your page is blank, you have an PHP-Error somewhere.